# How to create a new civilization mod for Age of Empires 1 Definitive Edition?

Tags: modding, steam

I want to make a mod for Age of Empires 1 Definitive Edition, in which I split an existing civilization (Phoenicians) into two civilizations:

- **Eastern Phoenicians:** Primarily representing Canaanites
- **Western Phoenicians:** Primarily representing Carthaginians

I want to do so to fix an historical mistake in the development of AOE1 in which the Phoenician tech tree includes war elephants:
As far as I know --- none of the Eastern Phoenicians regularly used war Elephants in their armies:

**Eastern Phoenicians from north to south and west to east:**

```
Kingdom of Ugarit | Mittani polities
Kingdom of Tyre   | Kingdom of Aram-Damascus
Kingdom of Israel | Kingdom of Ammon 
Kingdom of Judah  | Kingdom of Moab
Kingdom of Edom   | Nabataean polities
```

### My problem

As a webmaster coding primarily in *Bash-HTML-CSS-JavaScript-Wiki-Markdown* stack who never wrote a GUI program with languages common for the task (such as XML, C++, C# and others) I have no idea where to start.

### My question

How to create a new civilization mod for Age of Empires 1 Definitive Edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I do not have this game, cannot test if it works correctly.*

I suggest the open source tool [Advanced Genie Editor 2019](http://aok.heavengames.com/blacksmith/showfile.php?fileid=11002). ([github repository](https://github.com/Tapsa/AGE)).

On the linked website it says:

> **Advanced Genie Editor**
>
> for Age of Empires, Rise of Rome, Age of Kings, The Conquerors (including HD), Star Wars Galactic Battlegrounds and Clone Campaigns.
>
> This is a program for editing data of genie (DAT and DLL) files. It can edit properties of units, civilizations, technologies, graphics, terrains, sounds, player colors and some other things.

---

### Definitive Edition

It should work with the 2018 *Definitive Edition* if you select this version on the Genie version drop down list when opening files, as pictured below:

[image: Advanced Genie Editor "Open files..." dialog]

*Advanced Genie Editor "Open files..." dialog*

The application has support for editing tech trees among other things:

[image: Advanced Genie Editor main window, Tech Trees tab, no file open]

*Advanced Genie Editor main window, Tech Trees tab, no file open.*

That should allow you to remove access to particular units for given civilizations. Remember to backup your dat files.

I found this tool linked from [aoe.heavengames.com](http://aoe.heavengames.com/). *I did not see any real alternatives while searching.*

---

#### Update

I tried the tool on a friend's copy of the game. I had to put the path to the dat file manually. There is no language.dll file, so untick that when opening. There is an option to copy a civilization (on the "Civilizations" tab), and to disable units to particular civilizations (on the "Units" tab). However, editing the tech tree for a particular civilization was not available (there was no "Tech trees" tab).

Comment: Hello ; I thank you dearly for noting this --- just one point for future readers ; I am not sure it deals with Definitive Edition release from 2018 as well or only with the originals --- I have yet to buy the Definitive edition, I asked the question here on principal, for possible future times. Sadly I don't have enough reputation points to up vote your answer, at this point.

Comment: Dear Theraot - I was glad to read your answer, to upvote it a few days ago already and to you the bounty --- I waited a few days just a principle (and could wait about 4 more days + bounty grace period) but your work on this is in my opinion graceful and I also find it inspiring and of course I appreciate it much. I was glad to accept the answer and recommend users to upvote your answer.